# New Microsoft Teams: Getting error while removing tab from team

Tags: reactjs, microsoft-teams

Getting error while removing a tab from MS Teams team as '
There was a problem removing this tab
You can permanently delete this tab; however, it may not delete the data in this app. If you require the data of this app to be permanently deleted, then you should avoid this step.'

The app is running successfully.

I have tried clearing the cache of MS Teams.

This used to work 2 days ago and suddenly started coming for my 2 apps.

App details:  Team Scope, Configurable tab +bot, manifest version: 1.11

Please let me know if any further details are required.

Comment: how are you trying? is this a programming question at all?

Comment: Could you please confirm whether you have added multiple configurable tabs and trying to remove via right click on it? Please confirm if you are following this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/create-tab-pages/removal-page?tabs=teamsjs-v2

Comment: My tab is single and configurable. I am returning app.notifySuccess(); in the tab removal page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you are handling the tab removal process correctly in your app.

1. In your tab removal page logic, you need to invoke the registerOnRemoveHandler event handler. This handler will be triggered when the user attempts to remove the tab configuration. Make sure you have only one remove handler registered at a time.
2. Within the remove handler, you can designate the tab content to be removed and/or archived. You can use the getConfig() function to retrieve the Config object, which provides the valid settings property values. Update the contentUrl property of the configuration object to specify the URL of the content to be removed.
3. After handling the removal logic, you need to notify Teams about the outcome of the removal process. If the removal of the underlying resource succeeded and its content can be removed, you should call the notifySuccess() function of the RemoveEvent interface. If the removal failed, you can optionally call the notifyFailure(string) function, providing a reason for the failure.